# What is the meaning of this curve in the graph of equation x^x=y^y?

Tags: exponential-function, exponentiation

Using Desmos I plotted the graph of equation $x^x = y^y$ which looks like this
[image: Graph of x^x = y^y]
According to my understanding the solution to this Equation should have been only $y=x$ but the curve seems to prove me wrong.
So, what is the reason of that curve from $(0,1)$ to $(1,0)$ and what is the value of $x$ where the Curve intersects with line (I mean how can we calculate its value algebraically)?

Comment: Take $\log$ on both sides. Then note that $x \log(x)$ takes each function value (except the minimum) twice for $0 \leq x \leq 1$. That’s the other component that you see in your picture.

Comment: It looks like the curve intersects the line at $x=\frac{1}{e}$, but I have not proved this.

Comment: @WimC Sorry but could you please elaborate your answer as I wasn't able to understand what you are trying to explain.

Comment: @jasnee Thanks for your efforts. You seem to be right but I want the algebraic proof.

Comment: Hint: the global minimum of the graph $y = x^x$ is located at $x = \frac{1}{e}$.

Comment: @TomKern But my equation is $y^y = x^x$.

Comment: Seems like the answer to my question lies in the nature of Lambert W Function.